# How to remove permissions from a Facebook app?

Tags: facebook

My app has been approved `publish_actions`, but I no longer want this permission.

[image]

How can I remove it, such that my app does not request it?

[image]

Comment: You don't remove it. It just say you are approved to use it. You change your code to not ask the user for it

Comment: You are right. I changed `config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'], scope: 'publish_actions'` to `config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'], scope: ''` in `config/initializers/devise.rb` and that did the trick. Thank you!